# Unable to add custom config for spring security with oauth2

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have a spring boot app that works correctly with oauth2 (as a resource server). There is no custom `configure(HttpSecurity http)` method. Only

```
spring-boot-starter-security
spring-security-oauth2
spring-security-jwt
```

are added to pom.

Now i want to add endpoints that should be unprotected. So (following many SO responses) i started with adding:

```
@Configuration
public class Security extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    }
}
```

and then i got:

> Cannot apply org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer@6513fd22 to already built object

Full error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot apply org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer@6513fd22 to already built object
```

So how should i configure my security to add endpoints for anonymous access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error comes from empty body in `configure()` method.

You have to specify it explicitly. For instance (from a working application of us):

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/unprotected/sample/find/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/unprotected/another/register").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
            .csrf().disable();
}
```

Endpoints matching `/unprotected/sample/find/**` and `/unprotected/sample/find/**` are unprotected and everything else is protected.

Of course not protected endpoints should not have any `@PreAuthorize()` defined.